# Locking a private static object

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am wondering which following code is best:

```
private static volatile OrderedDictionary _instance;
private static readonly Object SyncLock = new Object();

private static OrderedDictionary Instance
{
     get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new OrderedDictionary()); }
}

 public static Mea Add(Double pre, Double rec)
{
     lock (SyncLock)
     {
        ...
     }
}
```

Or is it OK and better IMO just use the following?

```
private static volatile OrderedDictionary _instance;

private static OrderedDictionary Instance
{
     get { return _instance ?? (_instance = new OrderedDictionary()); }
}

 public static Mea Add(Double pre, Double rec)
{
     lock (Instance)
     {
        ...
     }
}
```

Based on Mike Strobel's answer I have done to following changes:

```
public static class Meas
{
    private static readonly OrderedDictionary Instance = new OrderedDictionary();
    private static readonly Object SyncLock = new Object();


    public static Mea Add(Double pre, Double rec)
    {
        lock (SyncLock)
        {
            Instance.Add(pre, rec);
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The latest version looks much better. These are static, so by definition you are only making one of them, and these objects are very cheap. There's no reason to go with a lazy solution unless you are making millions that are likely to be unused, or making them is very expensive.  And locks are cheap when not contended.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two pieces of code are **not** equivalent.  The former ensures that all threads will always use the same lock object.  The latter locks a lazily-initialized object, and there is absolutely nothing preventing multiple instantiations of your `_instance` dictionary, resulting in contents being lost.

What is the purpose of the lock?  Does the serve a purpose other than to guarantee single-initialization of the dictionary?  Ignoring that it fails to accomplish this in the second example, if that is its sole intended purpose, then you may consider simply using the `Lazy<T>` class or a double-check locking pattern.

But since this is a static member (and does not appear to capture outer generic parameters), it will presumably only be instantiated once per AppDomain.  In that case, just mark it as `readonly` and initialize it in the declaration.  You're probably not saving much this way.

Since you are concerned with best practices: you should *never* use the `lock` construct on a mutable value; this goes for both static and instance fields, as well as locals.  It is *especially* bad practice to lock on a *volatile* field, as the presence of that keyword indicates that you *expect* the underlying value to change.  If you're going to lock on a field, it should almost always be a `readonly` field.  It's also considered bad practice to lock on a method result; that applies to properties too, as properties are effectively a pair of specially-named accessor methods.

Comment: I recommend against the double-checked locking pattern. It is difficult to get right, and is only of benefit when there is high contention on the resource. The correct solution is not to go with a dangerous low-lock algorithm, it is to *eliminate the source of contention*.

Comment: Agreed.  Double-check locking is best avoided unless you _really_ understand what you're doing (i.e., you understand the nuances of the memory model).  Best to eliminate the problem altogether, i.e., get rid of the lazy initialization.

Comment: Thanks! Please see OP edit that reflect your input. I hope this time I got it right.

Comment: Looks good now, though I would personally move the dictionary initialization into the field declaration.  Just make sure you follow Eric's advice and guard _all other_ accesses to the dictionary too (including all reads/queries).  Remember: a lock is only useful if it is applied consistently :).

Comment: "I would personally move the dictionary initialization into the field declaration" not sure what you mean here, in your original answer you sad about moving it to the constructor...

Comment: Sorry, I meant move the `new OrderedDictionary()` constructor call (instantiation) into the field initializer: `private static readonly OrderedDictionary Instance = new OrderedDictionary();`.  Answer updated for clarity.  Placing it in the static constructor works just fine, so long as you mind the order of instantiations.

Answer (score 9):

Mike Strobel's advice is good advice.  To sum up:

- Lock only objects that are *specifically intended to be locks*.
- Those lock objects should be private readonly fields that are initialized in their declarations.
- Do not try to roll your own threadsafe lazy initialization. Use the `Lazy<T>` type; it was designed by experts who know what they are doing.
- Lock *all* accesses to the protected variable.
- Violate these sensible guidelines when **both** of the following two conditions are true: (1) you have a empirically demonstrated customer-impacting performance problem and solid proof that going with a more complex low-lock thread safety system is the only reasonable solution to the problem, and (2) you are a leading expert on the implications of processor optimizations on low-lock code. For example, if you are Grant Morrison or Joe Duffy.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not expose the `Instance` to other classes, the second approach is okay (but not equivalent). It's best practice to keep the lock object private to the class that is using it as a lock object. Only if other classes can also take this object as lock object you may run into issues.

(For completeness and regarding @Scott Chamberlain comment:)
This assumes that the class of `Instance` is not using `lock (this)` which contrary represents bad practice.

Nevertheless, the property could make problems. The null coalescing operator is compiled to a null check + assignment... Therefore you could run into race conditions. You might want to [read more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297705/how-to-implement-thread-safe-lazy-initialization) about this. But also consider to remove the lazy initialization at all, if possible.

Comment: With .NET classes you can be fairly sure you are are safe, however when working with a 3rd party library be wary of poor coding practices. If the class you are locking on uses `lock(this)` internally you could cause a deadlock if the right conditions are met. (still gave you a +1)

Comment: Thanks :) Included it in my post.

Comment: The second example is most definitely _not_ fine if the intention is for the two pieces of code to be equivalent (they are not).  Even if he eliminates the race condition, it is generally a very bad practice to lock on a mutable field, much less a _volatile_ field.