# simulate Lazy in Java8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, lazy-evaluation, evaluation

I wrote the following code to simulate `Lazy<T>` in Java:

```
import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class Main {

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface Lazy<T> extends Supplier<T> {
        Supplier<T> init();
        public default T get() { return init().get(); }
    }

    static <U> Supplier<U> lazily(Lazy<U> lazy) { return lazy; }
    static <T>Supplier<T> value(T value) { return ()->value; }

    private static Lazy<Thing> thing = lazily(()->thing=value(new Thing()));
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("One");
        Thing t = thing.get();
        System.out.println("Three");

    }
    static class Thing{ Thing(){System.out.println("Two");}}
}
```

but I get the following warning:

> "value `(T)` in Main cannot be applied to (`com.company.Main.Thing`) 
>   reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that `Supplier<T>`
>   conforms to `Lazy<Thing>`"

could you please help me find out what the problem is?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Follow [the template](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29141814/2711488) *strictly*…

Answer (score 3):

`Lazy` is a subclass of `Supplier` and you are trying to cast it otherways.

Changing

```
private static Lazy<Thing> thing = lazily(() -> thing = value(new Thing()));
```

to

```
private static Supplier<Thing> thing = lazily(() -> thing = value(new Thing()));
```

should work.

Answer (score 1):

`value()` returns a `Supplier`, while `thing` field has type `Lazy<Thing>`. You cannot assign a `Supplier` to a `Lazy` (with whatever parametrization) because not all `Supplier` instances are `Lazy` instances.

Further, `lazily()` return value (which is a `Supplier`) is tried to be assigned to the `thing`, and this is not gonna work for the same reason.

We can change `lazily` type to `Lazy` and remove that inline `thing=` assignment (which is inside `thing` initializer expression) to make it compile:

```
static <U> Lazy<U> lazily(Lazy<U> lazy) { return lazy; }
static <T> Supplier<T> value(T value) { return ()->value; }

private static Lazy<Thing> thing = lazily(()->value(new Thing()));
```

But I'm not sure whether this is what you wanted to get.

If you just wanted a lazy behaviour, `Supplier` itself is already capable of acting lazy as `get()` is only executed when requested to and not when a `Supplier` is created.

If you want a caching logic (only compute once, and only compute it needed), you could use something like this:

```
public class CachingSupplier<T> implements Supplier<T> {
    private final Supplier<T> supplier;
    private T cachedValue;
    private boolean computed = false;

    public CachingSupplier(Supplier<T> supplier) {
        this.supplier = supplier;
    }

    public T get() {
        if (!computed) {
            cachedValue = supplier.get();
            computed = true;
        }
        return cachedValue;
    }
}
```

If you want to guarantee that `supplier.get()` gets called at maximum once, you could apply some synchronization:

```
    if (!computed) {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (!computed) {
                cachedValue = supplier.get();
                computed = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return cachedValue;
```

Here, a [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) is used.