# What is the equivalent of Kotlin "by lazy" in Java?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm following this article https://proandroiddev.com/detecting-when-an-android-app-backgrounds-in-2018-4b5a94977d5c to implement android lifecycle but on a legacy app that has the Application class on java.

How can I implement this kotlin code in java?

```
private val lifecycleListener: SampleLifecycleListener by lazy {
    SampleLifecycleListener()
}
```

I feel that is a dumb question, but I'm not familiar with lazy initialization and I'm not sure how to search this question, any "lazy theory link" will be welcome also.

Comment: [Lazy Initialization in Kotlin](http://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-lazy-initialization) compares Java and Kotlin. *(A simple web search for [`kotlin lazy`](https://www.google.com/search?q=kotlin+lazy) found that easily enough, so "not sure how to search" sounds like "too lazy to bother searching myself", no pun intended)*

Comment: take a look at this question: [Lazy field initialization with lambdas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29132884/1429387) (java 8)

Comment: Lazy loading is not built into Java.  You must either implement it yourself (as in the answers below) or use a library that does it for you (for example, Spring).  It seems likely that there is an Android lazy initialization library since it is a fairly straight forward proxy technique.

Comment: @Andreas your link is gold, thank you, I really did my searches, but the main results are about lateinit vs lazy, etc. Probably I didn't enter on your suggestion because I thought it was another explanation for how and when to use lazy initialization so probably I ignored it.  Maybe you're true about how sounds "not sure how to search", I try to avoid answers about "search before ask!" without useful content. Not your case, now I learned a bit more about laziness :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
private SampleLifecycleListener sll;

public synchronized SampleLifecycleListener getSampleLifecycleListener() {
    if (sll == null) {
        sll = new SampleLifecycleListener();
    }
    return sll;
}
```

That way it isn't initialized until the getter is called.

Comment: how about `synchronize` in get function?

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc For multi-threaded support, `synchronized` may be too costly, so holder pattern is better. See example in [Lazy Initialization in Kotlin](http://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-lazy-initialization), which shows Java example too.

Comment: @KingfisherPhuoc Is there a need for that? This method will be called only in onCreate() and since it runs only on UI thread, it doesn't need any synchronization.

Comment: Thanks, forgot to add the synchronize.

Comment: One benefit Kotlin has over Java is that it allows you to lazily compute while still allowing nullability.

Answer (score 11):

You can call Kotlin `lazy` from Java if you want to:

```
import kotlin.Lazy;

Lazy<SampleLifecycleListener> lazyListener = kotlin.LazyKt.lazy(() -> new SampleLifecycleListener()));
SampleLifecycleListener realListener = lazyListener.getValue();
```

Comment: what if I want to add an argument in SampleLifecycleListener's constructor?

Comment: add argument in 

`Lazy<MfaChallengeViewManager> mfaLazyListener = kotlin.LazyKt.lazy(() -> new MfaChallengeViewManager(Arguments));`

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with Java 8, you can use [`ConcurrentHashMap#computeIfAbsent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to achieve laziness. `ConcurrentHashMap` is thread-safe.

```
class Lazy {
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, SampleLifecycleListener> instance = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(1);

    public SampleLifecycleListener getSampleLifecycleListener() {
        return instance.computeIfAbsent("KEY", k -> new SampleLifecycleListener()); // use whatever constant key
    }
}
```

You can use this like

```
SampleLifecycleListener sll = lazy.getSampleLifecycleListener();
```

Comment: Couldn't you just use a lock with the other solution? I feel like a map adds a bit of an overhead.

Comment: @Salem `ConcurrentHashMap` provides a high-performance, scalable, and thread-safe implementation of the `Map` interface. It uses fine-grained locking, called lock striping, to minimize contention and improve performance compared to using a synchronized code. The "Java Concurrency in Practice" book discusses `ConcurrentHashMap` as a preferred alternative to using `Collections.synchronizedMap()` or manually synchronizing `HashMap` operations (`synchronized` or locks).