# Using Java 8 Supplier in streams to achieve lazy evaluation

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, lazy-evaluation

I am trying to achieve lazy evaluation using Supplier in a stream like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Supplier<List<String>> expensiveListSupplier= getExpensiveList();
        getList().stream()
                .filter(s -> expensiveListSupplier.get().contains(s))
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Supplier<List<String>> getExpensiveList() {
        return () -> Stream
                .of("1", "2", "3")
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static List<String> getList() {
        return Stream.of("2", "3")
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

But this will call getExpensiveList() method for every element in the list.
I am trying not to be verbose and don't want to write something like this ie to add not empty checks and stuff.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Supplier<List<String>> expensiveListSupplier = getExpensiveList();
        List<String> list = getList();
        if (!list.isEmpty()) {
            List<String> expensiveList = expensiveListSupplier.get();
            list.stream()
                    .filter(expensiveList::contains)
                    .forEach(System.out::println);
        }    
    }

    private static Supplier<List<String>> getExpensiveList() {
        return () -> Stream
                .of("1", "2", "3")
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private static List<String> getList() {
        return Stream.of("2", "3")
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? Can you simplify .. *I am trying not to be verbose and don't want to write something like this ie to add not empty checks and stuff* ?

Comment: Can you just call `Set<String> expensiveStuff =  new HashSet<>(getExpensiveList().get());`. Using a set would scale up to any practical size with constant runtime.

Comment: A small note: supplier instance after it's been used, prevents it from being garbage collected and for parallel execution of streams, you can check this link https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-util-stream/lazy-evaluation.html     As  @Hoopje pointed better to go with your verbose code.

Comment: What’s the point of using a `Supplier` here? You need to get the list for the first element already, so the laziness is tiny, compared to the complication of your code.

Answer (score 3):

You second variant can be simplified to

```
List<String> list = getList();
if(!list.isEmpty()) {
    list.stream()
        .filter(getExpensiveList().get()::contains)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

It makes the use of a `Supplier` pointless, as even the call to `getExpensiveList()` will be done only when the list is non-empty. But on the other hand, that’s the maximum laziness you can get anyway, i.e. not to request the expensive list when the other list is empty. In either case, the expensive list will be requested for the first element already when the list is not empty.

If the expensive list can become large, you should use

```
List<String> list = getList();
if(!list.isEmpty()) {
    list.stream()
        .filter(new HashSet<>(getExpensiveList().get())::contains)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

instead, to avoid repeated linear searches. Or redesign `getExpensiveList()` to return a `Set` in the first place.

Comment: The reason of adding the second code snippet was to explain my question(first snippet) and not for improvements in it. I think your answers does not add value to my intended question. Thanks anyway for answering.

Comment: Doesn't this make a call to `getExpensiveList().get()` for every element of the stream?

Comment: @Amardeep I decided to provide an improved variant of your second code snippet, because it *looks* more complicated in your question while actually being simpler than your first variant. As already explained in my answer, your first variant does not provide any actual benefit, i.e. regarding the desired laziness. So there’s  a variant which is simpler but still without any drawbacks compared to the others. If that’s not an answer, you are perhaps asking the wrong question.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner no, a method reference of the `expression::name` form will evaluate the expression once and capture the result. See also [What is the equivalent lambda expression for System.out::println](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28025717/2711488)…

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Yes it will as I have pointed out in my question as well. And in top of it all this was the reason for putting up this question.

Comment: @Amardeep no, it will not. That’s a fundamental difference between a method reference of the `getExpensiveList().get())::contains` form and a lambda expression like `s -> expensiveListSupplier.get().contains(s)`.

Comment: Is the condition `!list.isEmpty()` needed?

Comment: @user7 not for the stream, but to avoid the invocation of `getExpensiveList()` and `getExpensiveList().get()`. A method reference of the form `expression::name`, like `getExpensiveList().get()::contains`, will evaluate `expression` immediately and capture the result, so it’s not executed for every stream element, but only once. But it also implies that it will be evaluated exactly once here, even when the list is empty—unless we wrap the entire statement with `if(!list.isEmpty())`. Of course, if the expression is cheap, like with `System.out::println`, we don’t need to care.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for the explanation :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible using only standard Java classes. But you could write your own lazy evaluator and use that, for example (untested):

```
public class LazyValue<T> implements Supplier<T> {
    private T value;
    private final Supplier<T> initializer;
    public LazyValue(Supplier<T> initializer) {
        this.initializer = initializer;
    } 
    public T get() {
        if (value == null) {
            value = initializer.get();
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

There are other possibilities as well, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29132884/lazy-field-initialization-with-lambdas).

But beware! If you add lazy evaluation, you have a mutable data structure, so if you use it in a multithreaded environment (or a parallel stream), add synchronization.

But, I would use your verbose version. It's immediately clear what it does, and it is only four lines longer. (In real code I expect that those four lines are irrelevant.)

Comment: I thought so!!. Just wanted to check if someone has figured out a solution which is concise and functional.