# Lock-free and wait-free thread-safe lazy initialization

Tags: java, multithreading, lazy-initialization, lock-free, wait-free

To perform lock-free and wait-free lazy initialization I do the following:

```
private AtomicReference<Foo> instance = new AtomicReference<>(null);  

public Foo getInstance() {
   Foo foo = instance.get();
   if (foo == null) {
       foo = new Foo();                       // create and initialize actual instance
       if (instance.compareAndSet(null, foo)) // CAS succeeded
           return foo;
       else                                   // CAS failed: other thread set an object 
           return instance.get();             
   } else {
       return foo;
   }
}
```

and it works pretty well except for one thing: if two threads see instance `null`, they both create a new object, and only one is lucky to set it by CAS operation, which leads to waste of resources.

Does anyone suggest another **lock-free** lazy initialization pattern, which decrease probability of creating two expensive objects by two concurrent threads?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom

Comment: @spudone thanks, I'm familiar with holder idiom, but unsure about its lock-freeness

Comment: It does, in effect, cause initialization to be serial, but this is less expensive than accidentally creating 2 (or more) objects, as you mentioned.

Comment: To get true lock freedom you will need to do some sort of spinning while the object is being created.

Comment: actually, there is no such thing like "lock-free thread safety", its logically impossible - because even complex work (re-)schedulers which "never wait" actually need at least one internal, transient & transparent or even invisible lock to keep data consistent and prevent corruption. But the amount of waiting / locking can be reduced to a **very** tiny & efficient minimum, that is correct.

Comment: i didnt join this conversation in order to "find flaws". To answer your implicit question : it will lock at least at `instance.get()` because thats how atomic fields work - they lock efficiently _(or sequentialize globally)_, copy data and unlock. In terms of java, an AtomicReference is mapped onto a native, atomic field - which is extremely efficient hence you may never actually "feel" the difference.

Comment: @specializt locking by parking a thread is very different from locking in CAS....

Comment: Why yes, yes it is. Well observed. This fragment of wisdom will help you in your quest for knowledge, hold on to it and _never_ let it go.

Comment: Jeez @specializt.  The term lock-free is well known and widely used.  There is no reason to argue such insignificant points in this case.

Comment: that doesnt change the fact that it describes something which literally can not exist. Its like talking about pure, frozen, burning H2O, or about perfect & complete, parallel processing within one single computer.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou What do you expect from your bounty? What is lacking in the current answers?

Comment: @assylias *"not enough attention"*--I believe it explains enough. I one of comments, I said that question is not very practical. I'm curious about this topic, and I have a reputation which I'm able to spend--so why not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement thread-safe lazy initialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297705/how-to-implement-thread-safe-lazy-initialization)

Comment: @Vadzim not exactly. "Thread-safe" in common sense doesn't include lock- and wait-free conditions.

Comment: @Alex, maybe. But singleton holder pattern there is lock and wait-free after first init for free. It's also less error-prone and more effective in most cases.

Comment: @Vadzim if you like singleton holder more and it suits your needs, please use it. I cannot understand what you mean by "less error prone". Easily understood by mediocre developers?--for sure, but I don't address them.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you want true lock-freedom you will have to do some spinning.  You can have one thread 'win' creation rights but the others must spin until it's ready.

```
private AtomicBoolean canWrite = new AtomicBoolean(false);  
private volatile Foo foo; 
public Foo getInstance() {
   while (foo == null) {
       if(canWrite.compareAndSet(false, true)){
           foo = new Foo();
       }
   }
   return foo;
}
```

This obviously has its problems of busy spinning (you can put a sleep or yield in there), but I would probably still recommend [Initialization on demand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom).

Comment: well, this is interesting, despite it is not wait-free. I should test it also.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Yes, I meant to use an AtomicBoolean

Comment: @SashaSalauyou And you're right it's not wait-free.

Comment: `AtomicBoolean` is not wait free, but since `getInstance()` is not synchronized the wait only occurs on the `canWrite.compareAndSet` instead of on the whole method. Since most of the time one thread will set `foo != null` the wait only occurs sometimes.

Comment: Take a read into http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Wait-freedom.  Wait-free has a specific meaning when talking about concurrent algorithms.  That is, a concurrent algorithm is wait-free if the operation is guaranteed to complete in a finite number of steps.  In the OP's example the maximum number of steps is 2.

Comment: In my example, it is unknown how long the operation for a non-instantiating thread will need to take. In practice it obviously won't be long, but without knowing exactly how many times a thread will spin, we lose the wait-free property.  This is how we reason between obstruction-free, lock-free and wait-free.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to have some synchronization for the object creation itself. I would do:

```
// The atomic reference itself must be final!
private final AtomicReference<Foo> instance = new AtomicReference<>(null);
public Foo getInstance() {
  Foo foo = instance.get();
  if (foo == null) {
    synchronized(instance) {
      // You need to double check here
      // in case another thread initialized foo
      Foo foo = instance.get();
      if (foo == null) {
        foo = new Foo(); // actual initialization
        instance.set(foo);
      }
    }
  }
  return foo;
}
```

This is a very common pattern especially for lazy singletons. [Double checked locking](http://www.javabeat.net/lazy-initialisation-singleton-and-double-check-locking/) minimizes the number of times the `synchronized` block is actually executed.

Comment: Thanks, I know this approach, but now I'm looking for lock-free one :)

Comment: May I ask why? The alternatives (spinning, using additional atomic variables) are not very appealing IMO and make things so much more complicated.

Comment: Atomic reference is used because it is CASed in other pieces of code.

Comment: I mean why you wanted lock-free init.

Comment: To achieve full lock- and wait-freedom. I agree, this question is not very practical. Curiosity.

Comment: You could also just initialize `Foo` when you declare it instead of lazy initialize it so there would be no need for the synchronized block.

Comment: You never call `AtomicReference.set(foo)` so every call to `getInstance()` will create a `new Foo()`

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with the lazy init Singleton pattern:

```
private Foo() {/* Do your heavy stuff */}

private static class CONTAINER {
 private static final Foo INSTANCE = new Foo();
}

public static Foo getInstance() {
 return CONTAINER.INSTANCE;
}
```

I do not actually see any reason on using an AtomicReference member field for itself.

Comment: What you offer is a common pattern but it is not lock- nor wait-free.

Comment: See in detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297705/how-to-implement-thread-safe-lazy-initialization

Answer (score 0):

What about using another `volatile` variable to lock?
You can do the double lock with new variable?

Comment: How will it help? Please provide an example.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if end result should be performance centric or not , if yes below is not solution . can you please check twice for instance and after first check call thread.sleep method for random mili seconds less than 100 mili seconds.

```
private AtomicBoolean canWrite = new AtomicBoolean(false);  
private volatile Foo foo; 
public Foo getInstance() {
   if(foo==null){
          Thread.Sleep(getRandomLong(50)) // you need to write method for it
         if(foo==null){
            foo = new Foo();
      }
   }
   return foo;
}
```

Comment: below i was reading your comment to Yuri , "Thread.sleep() results a context switch" . can you help me understand this , i think it will resolve my age old problem . ithread.sleep helps me controlling memory leaks by blocking thread processing . but still on some off day i get memory exception .

Comment: Your question is very generic and out of scope of discussion here. I suppose you should read about java memory model and garbage collection first.